# Struct comparer

Tags: c#, struct, comparison

I'm looking for theses two functions:

```
bool CompareEquality<T>(ref T struct1, ref T struct2); // where T: struct
int Compare<T>(ref T struct1, ref T struct2); // -1,0,1 for sorting
```

The second function treats structs like numbers. E.g. a 10-byte struct is simply compared like a 10 byte number.

Is there a way?
It should be efficient and not involve any copying of the structs, creating new buffers or arrays.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2zhzfk83(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: At least for the equality comparer, you have it built-in - see http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/valuetype.cs,43 and the corresponding implementation of the two methods used - https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/bc146608854d1db9cdbcc0b08029a87754e12b49/src/vm/comutilnative.cpp#L2583. Although it does involve boxing.

Comment: You say: _Unfortunately you cannot take pointers of struct types in c#._ What do you mean? If you have a concrete struct type, say `System.TimeSpan`, you **can** take a pointer to it if it does not contain any instance fields of reference type. If you have a type parameter `T` of a generic method, certainly you cannot take a pointer to a variable of type `T`. Not even if `T` has the value type constraint, `where T : struct`. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

As for C# 6.0 there is no way.